# How to remove image from title slide

Tags: beamer, titles, templates

Hi I use the command `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hfill\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{Images/red_logo.png}\hspace{0.2cm}\vspace{-1.35cm}}` to add an image to the top corner of every frame in Beamer. I want this image to be on every frame except the title frame. Can I change this command to exclude the title frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `plain` frame for your title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hfill\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}\hspace{0.2cm}\vspace{-1.35cm}} 

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

If you'd prefer an automatic solution, you could use the same trick as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1004#a1198

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{headline}{special headline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \hfill\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}\hspace{0.2cm}\vspace{-1.35cm}
}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@titlepage{%
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}[special headline]
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}
}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@titlepage}}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{abc}
cde
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```